# Reference for Hopf algebra applications to Feynman diagrams

Tags: reference-request, hopf-algebras, quantum-field-theory, coalgebras

I need to give a talk about Hopf algebras and I would like to give a (at least) 5 minutes introduction using Feynman diagrams as a motivation. I'm looking for a not-so-heavy reference explaining how the notions of product and coproduct arises from Feynman diagrams.

This was also posted on math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Alessandra Frabetti is a name that comes to my mind, but I am as far from understanding this subject as one can be.

Comment: http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0510202

Answer (score 3):

Have you had a look at the book by Connes and Marcolli "Noncommutative Geometry, Quantum Fields and Motives" (its available online [1](http://www.alainconnes.org/docs/bookwebfinal.pdf))?

The book first introduces Feynman diagrams and rules and then goes on to cast it in Hopf algebraic language.
I think I recall seeing some computations along the line of your question in there.

Comment: I'm checking that one and this publication of Alessandra Frabetti http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~frabetti/papers/frabetti2007v1.pdf (thanks darij!)

Answer (score 1):

I guess this answer is way too late to be useful to the OP, but there's of course also the book "Knots and Feynman Diagrams" by Dirk Kreimer.

Answer (score 1):

I also guess my answer is  too late to be useful to the OP. I think it is not an easy work to  explain how the notions of product and coproduct arises from Feynman diagrams. Because I think you need much time (more than 5 minutes) to explain what is the Feynman diagram firstly. Why not use another combinatorical object---rooted trees? Just one minutes， all the audiences can know it. Maybe you can use Connes-Kreimor Hopf algebras to explain what you want.  What more， for the coproduct  of Connes-Kreimor Hopf algebras， there is an interesting combinatorics description. If you like， I suggest you to look Foissy's paper http://loic.foissy.free.fr/pageperso/p11.pdf